# WordPress плагин WPBakery Page Builder не работает для категорий. Как исправить?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть плагин WPBakery Page Builder. Для обычных страниц работает, все супер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но для категорий не работает.( Боль[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот настройки плагина, для каких страниц работать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нельзя редактировать категории и теги через WPBakery потому что там нет текстового редактора.  Подробнее по ссылке
https://visualcomposer.com/help/faq/can-i-edit-category-and-archive-pages/

Но у WPBakery есть аддон который позволяет это делать другим способом подробнее по ссылке
https://visualcomposer.com/help/theme-builder/archive-page-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPBakery Page Builder поддерживает только страницы, в которых определено содержимое.

Категория, тег имеют другую структуру и генерируют содержимое автоматически.

Но есть возможность создавать собственные шаблоны для категорий через [Visual Composer Website Builder Archive Page Editor](https://visualcomposer.com/help/theme-builder/archive-page-editor/)